# Call to a member function result_array() on a non-object

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

help please I don't know what's wrong this is my model

```
    public function searchstudents(){
    $establishment_name = $this->input->post('name');
    $address = $this->input->post('address');
    $establishment_name2 = "Nicole's Apartment";


        $query = $this->db->query("SELECT u.id as id, u.first_name as firstname, u.middle_name as                  middlename, u.last_name as lastname, e.name as establishmentname FROM users u, beds b, room r, establishment e WHERE  r.establishment_id = e.id AND u.id = b.student_id  AND b.room_id = r.room_id AND e.name = '$establishment_name2' ");

  $this->db->query($query);

    return $query->result_array(); 

}
```

when I remove the AND e.name = '$establishment_name2' it works but when I include it it results to  Call to a member function result_array() on a non-object. I tried the query in the mysql and it works but it won't work in the codeigniter.

Comment: You can check the query and what is being sent to your db by printing out $query to your page:-) if it still does not make sense what the issue is. You can copy/paste the printed query into the SQL section for your actual database management system to test run it there. You can also catch little formatting errors by pasting the sql string into your favorite code editor. If there is syntax highlighting, you will see the issue for this query where the color changes at the apostrophe between your single quotes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's a tick issue:

```
$establishment_name2 = "Nicole's Apartment";
```

becomes:

```
e.name = 'Nicole's Apartment'
```

in your query

use addslashes() or escape like Mudshark said

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape `$establishment_name2`:

```
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT u.id as id, u.first_name as firstname, u.middle_name as                  middlename, u.last_name as lastname, e.name as establishmentname FROM users u, beds b, room r, establishment e WHERE  r.establishment_id = e.id AND u.id = b.student_id  AND b.room_id = r.room_id AND e.name = ".$this->db->escape($establishment_name2));
```

Answer (score 0):

Noooo, look you can do this directly

```
$this->db->query('SELECT u.id as id, u.first_name as firstname, u.middle_name as                  middlename, u.last_name as lastname, e.name as establishmentname FROM users u, beds b, room r, establishment e WHERE  r.establishment_id = e.id AND u.id = b.student_id  AND b.room_id = r.room_id AND e.name = ?', array($establishment_name2));
```

$this->db->query() accept 3 parameters:

```
1 - Query
2 - Array (with parameters, all parameters are clean)
3 - Escape string.
```

Comment: Man, look this page
https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/queries.html

Comment: And look this (more organized)
`$this->db->select('
        u.id as id,
        u.first_name as firstname,
        u.middle_name as middlename,
        u.last_name as lastname,
        e.name as establishmentname
    ');
    $this->db->from('users u, beds b, room r, establishment e');
    $this->db->where('r.establishment_id', 'e.id');
    $this->db->where('u.id', 'b.student_id');
    $this->db->where('b.room_id', 'r.room_id');
    $this->db->where('e.name', $establishment_name2);`